# Is there a way to "lock" requests in tornado until something is done?

Tags: python, tornado

when i say lock ,i mean it switch to other coroutines and switch back until certain work is done.

the code would be write like these:

```
@waitUntil('myProcess')
@gen.coroutine
def query():
    do_query()


@waitUntil('myProcess')
@gen.coroutine
def process():
    result = yield do_myProcess(params)
    deal_result(result)
```

here's my waitUntil based on the answer toro.Lock. don't guarantee it is right,need test.

```
import toro

_locks = {}

def getLock(key):
    if key not in _locks:
        _locks[key] = toro.Lock()
    return _locks[key]


def waitUntil(key):
    def wrapped(func):
        @gen.coroutine
        def wrapped2(*args,**kwargs):
            with (yield getLock(key).acquire()):
                result = yield func(*args,**kwargs)
            return result
        return wrapped2
    return wrapped
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [toro.Lock](https://toro.readthedocs.org/en/stable/classes.html#lock), which I wrote for this purpose

```
lock = toro.Lock()

@gen.coroutine
def f():
   with (yield lock.acquire()):
       assert lock.locked()

   assert not lock.locked()
```

https://toro.readthedocs.org/en/stable/classes.html#lock

Answer (score 0):

Since v4.2, tornado has locks: https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/locks.html

try locks.Lock:

```
>>> lock = locks.Lock()
>>>
>>> async def f():
...    async with lock:
...        # Do something holding the lock.
...        pass
...
...    # Now the lock is released.
```

see Lock documentation: https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/locks.html#tornado.locks.Lock